# How to modify the data grid to get some space after the last row

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have my datagrid which allows drag and drop from a list control.
So when ever i drag and drop a listbox item the datagrid is adding a new row.
but i have a requirement says that between last row and the data grid should have some space because users should not feel that the datagrid is full. how shall i achieve this.
I am using normal Windows.Controls.DataGrid.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how your `DataGrid` and its binding exactly looks like - and also how your extra space is expected to look like:

This

```
<DataGrid x:Name="yourGrid" CanUserAddRows="true" ...
```

will add a blank row at the end of the DataGrid, so the user is invited to drag and drop the listbox item to the end of the grid as well in order to append it